# Error: A security token validation error occured for the received JWT token. Http Status Code: Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, jwt

When I try to deploy an Azure 2.2 application with ASP.NET Web Role I get the following error message:

> Error: A security token validation error occurred for the
>   received JWT token.  Http Status Code: Unauthorized  OperationId:

I have a subscription and I logged in when I deployed.

Previously I was getting this error message:

> Instance 0 of role xxy is in an unknown state

Why do I get this exception and how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm getting this whilst trying to upload a MongoDb replicaset, are you doing something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I found that downloading the publish settings from the azure portal, or just recreating the deployment profile in vs2013 and saving it fixed the problem.

Try deleting your deployment (not your service) and publishing again.

Answer (score 1):

Check for validation warnings and see if any of those can be fixed. I started getting this same error after updating some of the azure/asp packages in the project. There were no build errors but I was unable to deploy it to the cloud. After fixing a few assembly binding redirects I noticed in the warnings everything worked again.